# reemplazar "," por "." para poder tratar la cantidad como un float

Tags: python, pandas

Una columna llamada `age` , que debe contener solo datos `int`, posee 2 campos con valores separados por "," la cuestion es que necesito pasar ese caracter a "." paraa poderlo trabajar, les dejo  lo que tengo hasta ahora

```
df['age'].replace(',' , '.', inplace=True) 

df['age']
```

el resultado es:

```
8        41
9       NaN
10       19
11      NaN
12       16
13     **38,5**
```

alguna idea muchas gracias..

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Cuales son los datos de entrada? ¿Que es lo que esperas?

Comment: @patricio moracho, ya lo resolvi, cambiando de metodo! gracias!!!